# Why do we need to call super(view) in ViewHolder constructor?

Tags: java, android

For implementing any RecyclerView we need to make ViewHolder constructor.
This is example from developer.android.com:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }

        public TextView getTextView() {
            return textView;
        }
    }
```

I cant understand why do we need to call super(view)? It`s for calling constructor of abstract class RecyclerView.ViewHolder? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The abstract class `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` has a `public final View itemView` member which is assigned when `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`'s single constructor `public ViewHolder(View itemView)` is called. If you do not call `super(view)` in an extending class' constructor, then `itemView` will not be assigned, leading to a multitude of problems.

It's easier to see if you look at the [`RecyclerView.ViewHolder` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/247185b98675b09c5e98c87448dd24aef4dffc9d/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#1940).

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView.ViewHolder class does not have a default parameterless constructor. It has a constructor which takes View type as an argument.
since there is no default constructor it is mandatory to call any of the superclass constructors from the child class constructor.

Note: Before asking questions I would recommend you to search for it on the web before posting questions to stackoverflow.